# C# DocX Create File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, docx

I want to create, write and read a word file with C#. I was using the DocX Library.

I've tried it in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code as well and got the following Error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.'

at Xceed.Document.NET.Document.PrepareDocument(Document& document, DocumentTypes documentType) at Xceed.Words.NET.DocX.Create(String filename, DocumentTypes documentType) at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 13

On english: The system can't find the given file.

I was using the latest version of DocX: 2.2.0

If you have an alternative library I could also possibly use it, I just need to be able to write, read and delete word files (.docx).

My Code:

```
using System;
using Xceed.Words.NET;
using Xceed.Document.NET;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\Test\Test.docx";

            var doc = DocX.Create(fileName);

            doc.InsertParagraph("Hello Word");

            doc.Save();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add DocX as a NuGet package? If not, you should. That will hopefully take care of any additional dependencies.

Comment: I just tried installing the DocX NuGet package and there were no dependencies. I just tried your code and, with a change of path to my Documents folder, it worked as expected. I have no reference to System.IO.Packaging.dll. This was in VS 2022 and targeting .NET 4.8. What .NET Framework version are you targeting?

Comment: Thank you! I've got an yellow Warning Sign (Yellow Triangle with an ! in the center) where was standing: Package 'DocX 2.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: You have tagged this question VS 2010. How can you possibly be targeting .NET 5 in that version of VS? Don't apply irrelevant tags to a question.

Comment: The docs say that there are differences between DocX and xceed (the commercial version), [one difference being](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) that xceed "is available on .NET 5 for .NET 5/6 Applications". Seems that you can use DocX only in a .net Framework project.

Comment: Based on the information at the NuGet site, that package supports only .NET Framework, not .NET Core. .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core.

Comment: Did you download the DocX plugin correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue here in that the DocX NuGet package doesn't install all of the DLLs required for use with the latest versions of .NET.
From the Xceed Words (commercial release) help documentation.

> To use .NET 5 or .NET 6, you will also need 2 new DLLs, available on NuGet: System.IO.Packaging and System.Drawing.Common.

If your application is targeting .NET 6.0 (the default if you're using a recent download of Visual Studio 2022 say) then you should open up NuGet Package Manager for the Solution and install the above mentioned packages.
(Click on Browse, enter the exact naming and install the ones by Microsoft).

I have run your code with the Microsoft packages installed alongside the DocX package and it works.